# How to find duplicate and deactivate duplicates for user attributes

Tags: django, postgresql, django-orm

Suppose we have a model in django defined as follows:

```
class DateClass:
    user_id = models.IntegerField(...)
    sp_date = models.DateField(...)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(...)
    ...
```

I follow insert policy here, i.e, for a specific user there will be only one specific active date. That means, there will be only one active row for user=1 at date table for sp_date values 27/10/2021, 28/10/2021 and so one. There shouldn't be two active rows for 27/10/2021 for user=1, but for other users have there rows for 27/10/2021.  Whenever a date has to be updated, I deactivate (is_active=False) the previous row and add a new row for specific date.

I want to find duplicate active dates for each users in one single query, and then deactivate (set is_active=False) all the duplicate values except the last row (The row which was last inserted). Two rows will be duplicate if the values of user_id and sp_date are equal and both have is_active=True. I know how to find duplicates for a specific column which is fairly easy. But I can't think of something which can do the above task elegantly. I can only think of following approach:

```
for user in users:
    
    dates = DateClass(user_id=user.id, is_active=True)

    for date in dates:
        days = dates.filter(
            sp_date=date.sp_date, is_active=True
        )
        if days.count() > 1:
            last_day = days.last()
        days.exclude(id=last_day.id).update(is_active=False)
```

As you can see above one is not that efficient, as I have to loop through all users. Is there any way to do this more efficiently? I am using PostgreSQL for database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There a great answer for multiple duplicate fields queryset from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54251145/11225821) as i don't want to take the credit and also don't want to reinvent the wheel, so i will suggest that answer

For your case it should be:

```
from django.db.models import Max, Count

duplicate_date_class = DateClass.objects.values('user_id', 'sp_date') \
    .annotate(records=Count('user_id')) \
    .filter(records__gt=1)

# Then do operations on duplicates
for date_class in duplicate_date_class:
    DateClass.objects.filter(
        user_id=date_class['user_id'],
        sp_date=date_class['sp_date']
    )[1:].update(is_active=False)
```

If you want to avoid having duplicate set of multiple fields, i suggest taking a look at [unique_together](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/options/#unique-together) for model validation